# JQuery $(element).append() breaking script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append an element to another on click, and it doesn't work.  I'm checking to make sure the element both exists and that the child to be appended doesn't exist, and have used alerts to verify that this is all working as I'm thinking it is.  Even appending a plain div isn't working.  There is more after that part that should fire, and it only does if I comment the append line out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$(".servicesMain_services_list li").click(function() {
    var itemTitleId = $(this).attr("id").replace("servicesMain","servicesMain_infoBox");
    if ($("#"+itemTitleId).children(".servicesMain_infoBox_itemTitle").length < 1) {
        if ($("#"+itemTitleId).length > 0) {
            $("#"+ItemTitleId).append("<div></div>");
        }
    }
.
.
.

});
```

**EDIT: I had a typo.  Sorry all.**

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is your HTML?

Comment: You have a typo, the first letter of itemTitleId is capitalized on the breaking line.

Comment: @Joe: No it couldn't, because there is something after "servicesMain" in the id...

Comment: mVChr...Holy crap I feel stupid.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#"+ItemTitleId).append("<div></div>");
```

should be

```
$("#"+itemTitleId).append("<div></div>");
```